# How to execute git command in a identified path?

Tags: python, git

I want to execute git command in python program.
I have tried 
    os.system("git-command")
As we know, git command can be executed correctly only in the directories which contains repositories. I have tried to print current path and this path is not what I hope for, it does not contains repositories.
Now my question is how to execute git command in a identified path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`subprocess` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html); pick one of the functions that suits your needs (based on what output you need). The functions all take a `cwd` argument that lets you specify the directory to operate in:

```
import subprocess

output = subprocess.check_output(['git', 'status'], cwd='/path/to/git/workingdir')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [GitPython](https://pythonhosted.org/GitPython/0.3.1/tutorial.html):

```
from git import *
repo = Repo("/path/to/repo")
git = repo.git
print git.status()
```

Comment: This way needs module git, but I have not installed this module by now . Using module subprocess can solve my problem. Thanks anyway!